# What means "package-level exported"

Tags: go

I was looking into [this logger](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus). What this import exactly means?

> The simplest way to use Logrus is simply the package-level exported logger:

```
package main

import (
  log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
  log.WithFields(log.Fields{
    "animal": "walrus",
  }).Info("A walrus appears")
}
```

From the example it looks like that "built-in" log was replaces by the the above implementation. I couldn't locate any official/formal specs, probably I don't know how this feature is called.

Comment: That's nothing magical, that's just a normal import statement that specifies the package name how you want to refer to it. This is a file-level declaration, it doesn't replace anything anywhere else.

Comment: That import declares `log` as an alias for `logrus`.

Comment: The documentation is telling us that is simpler to use the package level logging functions than it is to [create a logger](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#New) and call methods on that logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a reference to the fact that there are functions exported directly at the package level.  That is, they do not require any type or variable reference to access those exported symbols.

The example in the.. um.. example, is the `WithFields()` function.

This is exported at that "package level", so all you need in order to reference that function is the package name (or alias).

In this case, the `logrus` package has been aliased as `log`, so the `WithFields()` function it exports can be called simply using:

```golang
    log.WithFields(/* etc */)
```

By contrast, the `Info()` function in the example illustrates a symbol (in this case a function) exported by another type in the `logrus` package; the `Info()` function here is called on a `logrus.Entry` reference (returned by the `WithFields()` function).

### What's the Big Deal?

Package-Level exports are very common in `go`; a package that didn't export anything wouldn't be very useful to anybody! :)

I'm not sure that they are explicitly referenced as "package-*level*" exports in general; usually they would just be "exports" or "exported symbols" etc.

They are called out specifically in the case of `logrus` because the package authors have used this to create a package that is 'compatible' with the standard `log` package in GoLang (which also uses "package-level" exports).

i.e. if you alias `logrus` as `log` then logrus provides a *superset* of the standard `log` package; this is deliberately so that existing code that uses the `log` package can be converted to `logrus` very quickly by simply changing the import statement in files that make `log` calls.